# Add +1 to a value of a row everytime a new row is inserted in a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 columns in SQL table:
Ex:

```
|| ID || Name    || Position ||
   1    Robert        1
   2    Superman      2
   3    Spiderman     1
   .     .            .
   .     .            .
  1080   Herry        1
```

and i want to select data from same table and insert integer same table with the help of following Command:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Position)
SELECT NAME, Position FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (2,3)
```

The value(Table1.Position) of the newly created rows should not be same as the old one but start from 1 as soon as command will be called and increase(1) every time a new row will be added.
For ex. : When i call following:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Position)
SELECT NAME, Position FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (2,3)
```

The Table should look like this

```
|| ID || Name    || Position ||
   1    Robert        1
   2    Superman      2
   3    Spiderman     1
   .     .            .
   .     .            .
  1080   Herry        1
  1081   Superman     1
  1082   Spiderman    2
```

Position value can be anywhere between 1 and n. where n is dependent on the no. of rows inserted with the same command and increase by 1 and everytime again a new command will be called, the Position/n value should start from 1 and is not dependent on the recent/old/last row Position value.

Comment: How does `Herry` appear in the result set?

Comment: You can put auto increment to position column

Comment: Do this `SELECT NAME, Row_Number() over (order by Id) as [Position] FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (2,3)`, instead of selecting Position that has old value

Comment: So, for every `n`-row insert statement, the set of rows inserted should be assigned unique `Position` values in the range `1-n`? Is there anything that should control which rows are assigned specific values?

Comment: There are some other values between Table1.ID 3 and 1081 and skipped them with dots. Herry is just a value with Table1.position =  1 . I think, i understood your question correctly .

Answer (score 2):

I assuming you want the limit the position by 2 every time when the data inserted
for that here is some approaches here use `row_number()` function

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Position)
SELECT NAME, 1+((row_number() over(order by id)-1)%2) Position 
FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (2,3)
```

Second one is create sequence available from **SQL Server 2012+**

```
create sequence dbo.sq
start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue 1
maxvalue 2
cycle
```

**AND**, use that by calling `NEXT VALUE FOR` function

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Position)
SELECT NAME, next value for dbo.sq Position 
FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (2,3)
```

**EDIT :**  If you want to just give the position to the Name then use `row_number()` with order by...

```
SELECT NAME, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) Position 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ID IN (2,3)
```

Comment: No, it can be more than 2. between 1 and + infinity .

Comment: @MichealChoudhary for that use first approach like `SELECT NAME, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) Position 
FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Position) (
    SELECT Name, row_number() over(order by Position) Table1 
    WHERE Position IN (2, 3)
)
```

Comment: Any `OVER()` clause that uses the same columns or expressions in both the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses is almost certainly broken.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the ID column as IDENTITY (1,1). such that each entry to the table with start with 1 and incremented by 1.